# Does ZFS reads and writes show up in vmstat -p output

Tags: solaris, zfs, virtual-memory, vmstat

I am aware of ZFS not using the regular file system cache for caching pages for reads or writes (ZFS uses ARC and ZILs).

My question is would "vmstat -p" on a recent Solaris machine also reflect read and write activity performed by ZFS, in the form of fpi, fpo columns?

Let's assume that the machine is running ZFS as the only filesystem (Solaris 11.3).

Comment: Interesting question.  I have a Solaris 11.2 install with nothing but ZFS filesystems, and I can't get anything but zeros in those columns in a few short tests.